# Reading in parquet files with spark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, error-handling

I run into this issue when trying to read parquet files:
sidenote: I can read 1 parquet file if I do it like this:

```
account_info_df_porsche = spark.read.parquet('./Data/Porsche/Bronze/account_info_Prosche_df_all/part-00000-ea70435f-5dec-4a6e-9903-a51a9523c1ff-c000.snappy.parquet')
```

but I want to read all the parquet files inside the folder

python version: 3.11.6

Java version: "17.0.9" 2023-10-17 LTS

I have added the correct path variables in windows like my groupmates, because they can run it

```
Code:

account_info_df_porsche = spark.read.parquet('./Data/Porsche/Bronze/account_info_Porsche_df_all')


Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.parquet.:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1454)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.listLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.$anonfun$parallelListLeafFilesInternal$1(HadoopFSUtils.scala:95)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFilesInternal(HadoopFSUtils.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.bulkListLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.refresh0(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.<init>(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createInMemoryFileIndex(DataSource.scala:539)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:563)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed it by trying to click on the winutils.exe file and it said that I was missing msvcr120.dll, so I installed the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 and it worked now!

Comment: I followed the instruction from https://www.sts-tutorial.com/download/msvcr120